# find where is my windows os installed on from remote computer?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2008

I want to find location of 'cmd.exe' or 'powershell.exe' from remote computer. I want to execute a script from remote computer. To execute it I want location of 'cmd' or 'powershell.exe'. It is possible that windows is installed on any drive. so how to find where is my windows is installed.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305792

Comment: @Pekka웃  i have credentials for a remote windows machine. though code, i want to find on which drive windows is installed on remote windows machine.

Comment: `WINDIR` and `SYSTEMROOT` seem to be environment variables that do this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 I'd be surprised if this were really necessary, though.

Answer (score 3):

It's available via WMI ([Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx))

```
wmic.exe /NODE:<remote_computer> OS GET WindowsDirectory
```

Comment: Congratulations. You are the only one that noticed the "remote computer" part.

Answer (score 0):

To get the path + file of cmd.exe you can use this variable: `%ComSpec%`, which will return `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` in most cases. To get only the path to that location, you can use for instance (in the cmd)

```
for /f %a in ("%ComSpec%") do echo %~dpa
```

or (in a batch-file)

```
for /f %%a in ("%ComSpec%") do echo %%~dpa
```

Comment: for using any system or local variables...user needs to manually log in to machine. which is not the case. i have tried your approach, it is good, bt not of my use, if user hasn't logged in a single time.

Answer (score 0):

Use %WINDIR% environment variable

**Example:**

```
set "_path=%WINDIR%\system32\cmd.exe"        --> sets _path variable
cd /d %_path%                                --> goes to _path folder
```

Comment: to get %path% variable or any other system variable..user needs to manually log in atleast once. which is not the case here.